# Naming multiple lists and sets for different .txt's python

Tags: python

Well, I'm still new to python and I'm a little bit confused of my task right now. I have some Objects given (the amount could be up to 100), and I need to calculate some things for them and save the results in different .txt-files. I did the task only for one Object:

```
Object = [1., 0., -1.]
repeated_given_time, repeated_given_space, calculated_time_and_space = [], [], []
results = open('Object.txt', 'a')
```

(here is some omitted code which reads the data from a file (this file remains the only, independent of amount of Objects) and puts the data into `repeated_given_time` and `repeated_given_space`)

```
unique = set(repeated_given_time)
```

(some other omitted code for calculating and putting some values in the `calculated_time_and_space`)

```
time_list = list(unique)
for i in range (len(time_list)):
    print (time_list[i], calculated_time_and_space[i], file = results)
```

And I have absolutely no idea, how to do these things for multiple Objects in a loop. Obviuosly, I have to create much more of these lists `repeated_given_time_N, repeated_given_space_N, calculated_time_and_space_N` where N take values from 1 to N = 100 for 100 different Objects.

I know how to create multiple lists, but I couldn't find the efficient method of naming them.

The same thing with creating of multiple .txt's. How can I define their names like `Object_N.txt` with N from 1 to 100?

It would be great if someone can help me with that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a variable number of variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1373164/953482). Short answer: when you think you need variables `thing_1`, `thing_2`, ... `thing_n`, use a single list `things` instead.

Comment: Yes, this also helped. Ty :)

Answer (score 0):

If i understand well, you want to create multiple files that differs from one number. If so, you can do something like:

```
for i in range(10):
    f = open('Object_%s.txt' % i,'w')
    f.write('blabla')
    f.close()
```

This will create 10 files `Objects_N.txt` with N from 0 to 9.
Else feel free to correct me.

Comment: TY very much for the answer. But I still have a problem with accessing these files. They all have the name `f` if I understand it right. How can I access e.g. Only the Object_1.txt?

Comment: ...I need it for saving the calculated data there. I would use for it this: `print (<data>, file = f)` and I'm not sure in which .txt the data will land.

Comment: `f` is the current open file. If you need them open all at once, you can create a table of files. `f = [open('Object_%s.txt' % i,'w') for i in range(10)]` This way you can access each one of them with `f[i]`